# Getting CORS error when using PassportJS for Google OAuth in React/Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, google-oauth, passport.js

Despite looking for hours I cannot find a solution to my simple cors error. I am getting the following the in the browser:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=profile%20email&client_id=******.apps.googleusercontent.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/auth/google') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I just replaced the client ID for security reasons for this post.
**When I make this call in Postman/Thunder Client it gives back a 200 response and seems to work fine**

So I have tried using cors NPM package in express `app.use(cors());` also tried using this function in server.js `app.all("/*", function (req, res, next) { res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); next(); });` I've also tried using `

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy("/api/auth/auth/google", {
          target: "https://localhost:3000/",
          changeOrigin: true
    }));
}
```

I've just about done every solution in the book I found on SO, and none have seemed to work thus far. Any help would be so appreciated **Here is my code:**

**Package.json** in client

```
{
  "name": "tasktracker",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Homepage.js**

```
import React from "react";
import API from "../components/utils/API";

export default function HomePage() {
  const handleLogin = () => {
    API.login();
  };
  const testing = () => {
    console.log("Hello world!");
    API.testing();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Let's login with Google</h1>
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
      <button onClick={testing}>Testing</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**API.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  login: function () {
    return axios.get("/api/auth/auth/google");
  },
  testing: function () {
    return axios.get("/api/auth/test");
  },
};
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const routes = require("./routes");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

// Define middleware here
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
require("./config/passport");
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Add routes, both API and view
app.use(routes);


// Start the API server
app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`  ==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`);
});
```

**auth.js** (auth routes)

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const cors = require("cors");
const CLIENT_HOME_PAGE_URL = "http://localhost:3000";

/Route is api/auth/test
router.get("/test", function (req, res) {
  res.send(console.log("Test to backend"));
});


//Route is api/auth/auth/google/callback
router.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: CLIENT_HOME_PAGE_URL,
    failureRedirect: "/",
    session: false,
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    var token = req.user.token;
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000?token=" + token);
  }
);


  //Route is api/auth/auth/google/
router.get(
  "/auth/google",

  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

module.exports = router;
```

**Passport.js**

```
var passport = require("passport");
var GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth").OAuth2Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID:
        "*****",
      clientSecret: "*****",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3001/api/auth/auth/google/callback",
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      var userData = {
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        name: profile.displayName,
        token: accessToken,
      };
      done(null, userData);
    }
  )
);
```

I know it's a bit of a long post, if anyone has any ideas or solutions would greatly help me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem recently. Using

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/google"
```

instead of

```
axios.get("/api/auth/auth/google")
```

solved the problem.

On successful authentication, if you want to redirect the user to the original url on which the user made the login request, you can do this...

```
const currentUrl = window.location.href
const encodedParam = encodeURI(`?redirectUrl=${currentUrl}`)
window.location.href = `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/google${encodedParam}`
```

Store the redirect value in a session

```
req.session.redirectPath = req.query.redirectUrl
```

and after authentication, use this in your callback route